# How to test django model method __str__()

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models

I trying to test __str__ method, and when trying to access it in my test it returns my model instance (I think it is)

```
def test_str_is_equal_to_title(self):
    """
    Method `__str__` should be equal to field `title`
    """
    work = Work.objects.get(pk=1)
    self.assertEqual(work.__str__, work.title)
```

And from test I get:

```
AssertionError: '<bound method Work.__str__ of <Work: Test title>>' != 'Test title'
```

How I should compare these 2 values to pass test?

Comment: Did you try `self.assertEqual(work.__str__(), work.title)`? Even better, `self.assertEqual(str(work), work.title)`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#str):

> `Model.__str__()`
>
> The `__str__()` method is called whenever you call
>   `str()` on an object.

You need to **call** `str()` on the model instance:

```
self.assertEqual(str(work), work.title)
```

Comment: I see, that this is an old topic, but I would like to ask, how would it be done to call it for all models? In the example he is testing `str()` only for the `Work` model, or am I wrong?

Comment: Is `__str__` called when `print` is evoked?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you may simply call it like:

`model_instance.__str__()`