# Why my model's __str__ method return a Queryset only when testing?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model that have a `__str__` method that returns a string as expected, but when testing the `__str__` method it returns a Queryset and the test fails. Why this happens? I am already calling the method using `str()` instead of `__str__()` as this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077509/how-to-test-django-model-method-str) suggested

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In the shell it returns the username from the corresponding User object as a string, as expected:

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
str(author)
'edumats'
```

But when testing the `__str__` method of the model, the test fails, as the method returns a Queryset:

The test:

```
def test_author_methods(self):
        author1 = Author.objects.filter(user__username='Test User')
        self.assertEqual(str(author1), 'Test User')
```

The error from the test:

```
FAIL: test_author_methods (posts.test_models.PostTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edumats/Projects/blog/blog/posts/test_models.py", line 37, in test_author_methods
    self.assertEqual(str(author1), 'Test User')
AssertionError: '<QuerySet [<Author: Test User>]>' != 'Test User'
- <QuerySet [<Author: Test User>]>
+ Test User
```

Comment: `.get()` method returns the object whereas the `.filter()` method returns a queryset. So to fetch the username of first user you could do the following : `author1 = Author.objects.filter(user__username='Test User').first()`

Comment: Thank you @AjayLingayat I forgot that .get() and .filter() return differently. Using first() solved the issue.